# Viewpager not getting last item

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am using two `Viewpager` in my app,

1) First `Viewpager` displays images only

2) I am displaying price

now the issue is i have 4 images displaying in my viewpager1, and in second pager i have price as per selected product. first time it does not show anything, but when i scroll image and goes to next, it shows price..

```
 pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                Picasso.with(ProductLandingActivity.this)                            .load(categorylist.get(position).getProductLanding_packLink())
                        .error(R.drawable.nopreview )
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                        .into(selectedImage);

                System.out.println("Selected is"+position);
              selectedname.setText(categorylist.get(position).getProductLanding_packDesc());

                for (int i = 0; i < categorylist.get(position).getItems().size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("ProductPack_ID : " + categorylist.get(position).getItems().get(i).getPackSize_sellingPrice());


                }

                temp = categorylist.get(position).getItems();

              packadapter = new MyPacksPagerAdapter(ProductLandingActivity.this,categorylist);
                pagerpacks.setAdapter(packadapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }


        });
```

adapter

```
private class MyPacksPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<PackListModel> packsizedata ;

        public MyPacksPagerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<PackListModel> packsizedata) {
            this.context = context;
            this.packsizedata = packsizedata;

        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            final OneActor oneActor;

            View view;
            LayoutInflater infl = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = infl.inflate(R.layout.list_item_pagerpacktitles, container,false);
            oneActor = new OneActor();
           // oneActor.avatar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            oneActor.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_landing_packsname);
            oneActor.cmtCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_landing_packsprice);
            view.setTag(oneActor);


          oneActor.name.setText(temp.get(position).getPackSize_packSize());
            oneActor.cmtCount.setText(temp.get(position).getPackSize_sellingPrice());

            ((ViewGroup) container).addView(view);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View)object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return packsizedata.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view == object);
        }
        class OneActor{
           // ImageView avatar;
            TextView name,cmtCount;
        }
    }
```

By defaulat when i run the app it shows like this,in second pager it is not showing product price,

[image]

But when i scroll image it shows price

[image]

**My Expected output is**

[image]

This is my json response

http://pastebin.com/fbJang2B

Comment: add your logic in `onPageSelected`.

Comment: i tried that way.now when i scroll price list it crash invalid index

Comment: post your crash logcat and code of `MyPacksPagerAdapter `

Comment: i added my code in onpage selected..now it start index with 1..

Comment: @Pr38y can you tell

Comment: @chris ..You are not getting proper listview/gridview item click??? Is it your problem??

Comment: no its not about click..its about setting second viewpager item as per selected product from first viewpager

Comment: maybe you are using 1 in currentpage you need to use 0.

Comment: thanks for comment can you help me with that, what to change

Comment: it's true.. add your logical code in `onPageSelected`

Comment: plz..give me your JSON response with image

Comment: @aratikyada http://pastebin.com/p4kiC9qv

Comment: @aratikyada any clue mam?

Comment: Your JSON response is not correct..plz..check again.

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: you sure you don't have a problem with your xml?

Comment: in my xml what problem you think i have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as mentioned by @NotobharatKumar, you're loading the second adapter on a wrong event of the parent adapter, ie in `onPageScrolled` method. Second, you're setting a new adapter each time on that specific event, it seems useless. Finally, you are setting datas in an event, *(I'm not sure why you're doing this but)* I'd prefer to set it in a separate adapter and let the events listener for specific behaviors.

For me, it seems that you have two **separate** adapters, but **one datas list** shared by both. Assuming that, you have to set them both at start with their datas respectly, and on the event `onPageSelected` of the top adapter, you just have to automatically scroll the second. And if they have the same position in the list, `onPageSelected` should do the work correctly.

---

So, these modifications should solve your issue:

Your code in `onScrollChanged`, when you set the image and the text, seems really weird to me. I'd use a first adapter where I'll set all the datas like these two for the first `ViewPager`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstansteState) {
    ...
    // set a simple adapter for the first ViewPager
    FirstPagerAdapter imageadapter = 
             new FirstPagerAdapter(ProductLandingActivity.this, categorylist);
    pagerimages.setAdapter(imageadapter);
    ...
}
```

Then, as usual, set your datas in the FirstPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup container) {
    ...
    // set the content
    Picasso.with(ProductLandingActivity.this)                            
        .load(categorylist.get(position).getProductLanding_packLink())
        .error(R.drawable.nopreview )
        .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
        .into(selectedImage);

    selectedname.setText(
            categorylist.get(position).getProductLanding_packDesc());
    ...
}
```

Then no need to (re)load the image or the text when an event is triggered, since they will be holding by the adapter.

You only use `getPackSize_packSize()` and `getPackSize_sellingPrice()` in the second adapter, so you should create a separate list to only fill with these datas but outside the swiping event. Start by initializing the second list and the adapters:

```
// get the Items to fill the pack items list (like you did for `temp`)
ArrayList<Items> packItems = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < categorylist.size(); i++) {
    packItems.add(categorylist.get(position).getItems());
}

// fill the first adapter with your list of products (ie categorylist)
...
pagerimages.setAdapter(imageadapter);
...
// fill the second adapter with the pack items list
packadapter = new MyPacksPagerAdapter(ProductLandingActivity.this, packItems);
pagerpacks.setAdapter(packadapter);
```

**You have to do this when `categorylist` is created and populated**. So place this above code for example in your callback, when you retrieve the datas from your server.

Since the second list `packItems` is filling in the same order than `categorylist`, there will be no weird behavior by changing the both positions. 
Now, in the second adapter, it's preferable to use the local list `packsizedata`, as follows:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ...
    oneActor.name.setText(
            packsizedata.get(position).getPackSize_packSize());
    oneActor.cmtCount.setText(
            packsizedata.get(position).getPackSize_sellingPrice());
    ...
}
```

Finally, control the bottom `ViewPager` by using `onPageSelected` event of the first:

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, 
                            int positionOffsetPixels) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // set the second current page regarding the position of the first
        pagerpacks.setCurrentItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
});
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: @chris To me, `PackSizeModel` should be a class with only **two variables** `packSize` and `sellingPrice`, so you only need to found and add to the list only this Class filled in with these two datas. You're actually returning an arraylist of PackSizeModel, whereas you only want the datas.

Comment: what to change in code?  and how can i get solution

Comment: bro need your help can you tell what to change?

Comment: @chris `PackSizeModel` should be [something like this](http://pastebin.com/sN9V3MHn) and `getItems()` should return `PackSizeModel` and not an array. **Make some changes in `getItems()` to return the populated model and not an arraylist of this model.**

Comment: can you help please?

Comment: give mail id i send demo so that easily you will understand the issue

Comment: @chris I understood your issue as I saw your screenshot. But as I said three times now, you need to populate the model in getItems method and return this new model. I got nothing else to say. You need to make some basic researches, this is a minor issue that you should understand. I don't get what you don't understand with my comments... However, I'll try to help you another step, send me the getItems method in pastebin (or the full object class where getItems is in to).

Comment: i need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640025/how-to-store-call-records

Answer (score 2):

You should implement code for action at `onPageSelected` method because after page changed of your `ViewPager` then `onPageSelected` will be called.

Comment: position always start with 0. there must be something bug. can you share your code.

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: You have used two pager in your code. which one having issue?

Comment: when i scroll first view pager,second is not setting properly

Comment: I think you using wrong array at your adapter in method onPageSelected() please check.

packadapter = new MyPacksPagerAdapter(ProductLandingActivity.this,categorylist);

Comment: I guess there you have passed same array "categorylist‌" that you used in parent viewpage.